# How can I adequately prepare myself for a Master in Mathematics?

Tags: graduate-education, self-learning

I am an undergraduate student, studying towards a Degree in Applied Mathematics and Statistics. I am studying at an online university specialised in distance learning and I am therefore developing independent study skills.

Now, after achieving my degree I would like to get a Master Degree at the University of Bonn in Germany (the teaching language is English). I am therefore independently carrying out studies in Pure Mathematics to fill the gaps in my knowledge.

Please, I need detailed advice about adequately preparing myself for this goal, in particular about important topics to be covered and skills to be developed.

In particular, if anyone of you has attended undergraduate studies or a Master programme at the University of Bonn or in Germany in general, I'd like to read your advice and experience.

Any reply will be most appreciated

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This question already has 3 votes to close (for being too broad and off-topic).  To the OP and to those voting to close, you might want to read this meta thread: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/71/the-hitchkers-guide-to-make-questions-for-the-self-learner

Comment: Another related meta thread: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/256/77

Comment: Also relevant: http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/114/77

Comment: I would look at the list of courses taken by German students at that university at the bachelor's level that have some relevance to what you'll be studying at the master's level. Also, have a look at this list of books for prospective Columbia PhD students: http://www.math.columbia.edu/programs-math/graduate-program/what-graduate-students-are-assumed-to-know/ If somebody can point to an analogous list for a German university, that would be even better.